# Deprecated: Non-static method Category::objdb() should not be called statically in /home4/muqit117/kharredo.com/admin/models/Category.php on line 246

Tags: php, class

everything works fine except this error is showing on my page. when I add one product it shows for once when I add 2 it shows 2.the product is also added successfully.

```
public static function get_commissions($category_id, $product_id){

        $obj_db = self::objdb(); //here on this line error comes
        $query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE id=$category_id";
        $result = $obj_db->query($query);

        if($obj_db->errno){
            throw new Exception("Query Processing Error");
        }

        $data = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
        $commission = $data['commission'];

        $query = "SELECT price, user_id FROM products WHERE id=$product_id";

        $result = $obj_db->query($query);

        if($obj_db->errno){
            throw new Exception("Query Processing Error");
        }

        $data = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $user_id = $data['user_id'];
        $price = $data['price'];    

        if($user_id){
            $commission = array(
                'kharredo' => (($price*$commission)/100),
                'seller' => ($price - (($price*$commission)/100))
            );
            return $commission;
        }else{
            $commission = array(
                'kharredo' => $price,
                'seller' => $price
            );
            return $commission;
        }
    }
}
```

you can see that image[image]

this is the objdb function you can see in this

```
protected function objdb() {
    $obj_db = new mysqli;
    $obj_db->connect("localhost", "user", "password");
    if($obj_db->connect_error){
        throw new Exception("DATA BASE connection error");
    }
    $obj_db->select_db("muqit117_kharredo.com");
    if($obj_db->errno){
        throw new Exception("DATABASE error");
    }
    return $obj_db;
}
```

Comment: So show us how `objdb` is defined, I guess not as a static method!

Comment: protected function objdb() {
        $obj_db = new mysqli;
        $obj_db->connect("gator4068.hostgator.com", "muqit117_12345", "5Xx2Yy8Zz@@");
        if($obj_db->connect_error){
            throw new Exception("DATA BASE connection error");
        }
        $obj_db->select_db("muqit117_kharredo.com");
        if($obj_db->errno){
            throw new Exception("DATABASE error");
        }
        return $obj_db;
    }

Comment: So it is either `$obj_db = $this->objdb();` or change the function definition to `protected static function objdb() {`